# How to use variable based on function parameter received in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, repeat

How can I do this using only three lines instead of same three lines in 3 if statements?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhKfc.png)

Comment: Paste actual code.

Comment: It was showing error when I pasted code so had to paste the picture instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like I did in the `updateValues` method: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xkjmav?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks man this worked. What is this [] thing called btw. I am new to typescript.

Comment: It's not a TypeScript feature. It's a JavaScript one. This is how you can build dynamic object keys.

Answer (score 1):

(Please, don't paste code as link to images: we can't search it, we can't copy-paste it, etc).

I guess you could patchValue() using computed property values (and hope that you never make a typo, because now TypeScript compiler won't catch them), but may I suggest rethinking the form and making `custodian`, `requester` and `technical` separate form groups, each with its `phone`, `name` and `department` properties?

Comment: Here is a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-playground-vvp6zx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to a small example I was making for the answer. Since you already post it, you can add it to your answer.